# Adding text to existing PDF page in Cocoa under OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, pdf

I am struggling to get add text to an existing PDF page using PDFkit. Not sure if I need to go to the depths of CGPDF or I am missing something simple.

Here I am getting an existing single page PDF and (trying to) adding a line of text.

```
PDFDocument *thisPDF = [[PDFDocument alloc]initWithURL:PDFURL];
PDFPage *aPage =[thisPDF pageAtIndex:0];
NSRect pdfRect = [aPage boundsForBox:kPDFDisplayBoxArtBox];
[@“Text on PDF Page" drawInRect:pdfRect withAttributes:NULL];
```

I know I should add some attributes, which may be the issue, but I am looking for some guidance to how to just add the text at this point. I have been through the Quartz Guide, but this only references the CGPDF stuff, which I have tried and failed to implement successfully.

Can I do what I intend with just PDFKit? Am I heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Well, didn’t have to go as far as CGPDF, all that was needed was to subclass PDFPage and create a custom init method passing in the PDF page I wanted as the base, the overriding the following methods:

```
- (void) drawWithBox: (PDFDisplayBox) box
- (NSRect) boundsForBox: (PDFDisplayBox) box
```

Thanks to http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/207723-pdfpage-creation-query.html for pointing me in the right direction.